# What is the definition of a word?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, slang

I'm wondering what the minimal requirement for a word to be an actual word is. My *opinion* is that a word is a word if it can be understood and defined by everyone who hears it in conversation.

For example, let's say my friend and I are having a discussion about Quant Wall Street algorithmic traders. During the discussion I use words like "Quantism" and "Quantic" etc. They aren't words, but the meaning is immediately apparent and understood. Are these now English words?

Similarly a phrase like "I'm so sick, I'm going to vom"-- everyone knows what's impending.

Thanks for your time and input.

Comment: "A word is the smallest element that may be uttered in isolation with semantic or pragmatic content (with literal or practical meaning)." — [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word). Both *quantism* and *quantic* are words. *Vom* is just a word cut off — you say yourself that something is still impending. Nothing prevents you from using "vom" as a word in its own right, though, like *cas* or *pro*.

Comment: @RegDwighт  In fact, *vom* is a word; in theatres with vomitoria you'll often hear things like “Enter by the right vom” during blocking rehearsals.

Comment: @StoneyB A stage is not the whole world. The usual test for a string (one symbol or more) to be 'acceptable' as a word is its inclusion as such in a reputable dictionary. And, for the English language, the OED is generally accepted to be the reputablest.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well, you and Jaques can fight the first proposition out. I don't have access to any OED more recent than the 86 2nd Supplement; but I've been hearing *vom* since the 1960s, and if the current OED doesn't have it, that's their problem. I concur with OP: the only sure test for acceptability is acceptance.

Comment: Although the presence/occurrence of a particular gloss in the OED usually suffices that it be deemed “a word”, absence of the same by no means indicates that something is not one such.  Indeed, the OED’s own definition of “a word” is much broader than that.

Comment: Related, if not a dupe: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107865/on-words-and-their-existence-as-such

Comment: Collins 'defines' _word_ in the sense we're discussing as _one of the units of speech or writing that native speakers of a language usually regard as the smallest isolable meaningful element of the language_. Not strictly a definition - _which_ native speakers? - I'm sure nobody would claim they're all of one mind. As a classic example, a Collins 20th Century Dictionary (about 1980) entry read - **mirbane**: an apparently meaningless word. (That was a comment by Collins, not a definition.) Non-inclusion of a string in the OED should at least make us aware that there is no general acceptance.

Comment: 'My opinion is that a word is a word if it can be understood and defined by everyone who hears it in conversation.' Provided they (1) are English-speaking (2) are aged - what? ('By 14 months, the number of words understood jumps to 50 to 100') (3) are like me (Are Words Understood differently in different cultural Contexts? - http://www.antiessays.com/free-essays/383417.html (4) have what education? (5) have a standard passive vocabulary (6) don't have Alzheimer's ...

Comment: +1 Up voted assuming this is not a duplicate -- surprising the question has never been asked before.

Comment: "Can be understood by everyone who hears it" ... far too restrictive. Most words in my dictionary are not words by that criterion!

Comment: Have you considered checking a dictionary? That might provide some initial help.

Comment: I had to include this: 'As I watched a kid who looked tired from studying the dictionary for 14,793 straight hours attempt to spell “palatschinken”, I wondered, who in the world knows what that word means, let alone who uses it?  That got me thinking how many “words” there are that really no one would know exist and no one uses.  If use of a word -  and common understanding of a word – qualifies a word _as_ a word, then shouldn’t lack of use of a word and lack of common understanding of a word somehow disqualify a word as a word?' ( http://larrycheng.com/2009/05/29/what-makes-a-word-a-word/ )

Comment: Thank you to everyone who voted to close this (without providing input on on the sole basis of speed-reading the title) as "too basic; it can be definitively and permanently answered by a single link to a standard internet reference source designed specifically to find that type of information." The wholesome discussion on this topic proved that to be false.

The heart of this question is the evolution of language: for example "yolo," "twerk," and "rager" are now officially recognized in most dictionaries.

Comment: GEdgar -- that's a very interesting point and makes me think about the question in a new way. Thanks for that riposte!

Comment: I can't see how anyone can make the claim 'This question is too basic; it can be definitively and permanently answered by a single link to a standard internet reference source designed specifically to find that type of information.' John Lawler's first two sentences imply that, if anything, the question is **too difficult** rather than too simple.

Answer (score 4):

A word is a string of sounds or letters which can be identified as a grammatical unit, larger than a morpheme, but shorter than a phrase, and playing a structural role in a sentence.

Answer (score 3):

*Word* is not a term that has a single definition.

For one thing, what constitutes a word is different from language to language -- in polysynthetic languages, for instance, there's small difference between *word* and *sentence*.

For another, there are three common ways we use *word*
(the terms below are developed in P.H. Matthews' *Morphology*, Cambridge U Press):

1. We say the verbs *lie* and *lay* are different words, though they have some forms in common.
   This is the definition of *word* as **Lexeme**.
2. We say that the present tense form of *lie* is the word *lies*, pronounced /layz/.
   This is the definition of *word* as **Word-Form**, i.e, some particular form of a lexeme.
3. We say that a word pronounced /layz/ can have many meanings.
   This is the definition of *word* as **Phonological Word**, i.e, its pronunciation.

Here's [an illustration](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/3kindsofword.jpg) of how it works in English.

So, there is no single definition; it depends on how one is using the term.

You're quite correct, though, that speakers make up words on the spot all the time,
and  if they work and fill some need for others, they may be invented and used again.
But mostly they just die; sort of like mosquito eggs.

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't really address the issue - should strings like quantic, nudiustertian, vom, interphrastically, wumper, 1010-acid, irregardless, authoritativest, vonk, dfhnxd be allowed to be (1) used as words willy-nilly, (2) used as words with an accompanying glossary, (3) called words? And who decides where to draw the line? The OED isn't perfect, but has anyone any better ideas? The Urban Dictionary? (According to Wikipedia, "vonk" is a pseudoword in English, while "dfhnxd" is not.)

Comment: Any question about whether certain words ***should be allowed to be*** "used" in some fashion, or "called" anything at all, is already seriously silly. How in the world would such a decision be enforced, pray tell? And by whom? And on whom? And for what purpose? And -- as you correctly point out -- there isn't anybody with the authority to "draw the line". Except, of course, for [The Academy](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/academy.html), but that's already a well-established institution in Cloud-Cuckoo Land.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, words are never _strings_. That's an orthographic term, referring to writing, which is not language but technology. _Words_ are always spoken. Although they may be represented with more or less success in writing, written "words" are not really worda, but their shadow on the wall.

Comment: Really? **word**  (wûrd)
n.
1. A sound or a combination of sounds, or **its representation in writing or printing** (AHDEL) (bolding mine): the metonymy allows synonymy with _string_.                   And though the compilers at the OED use a descriptive approach, they certainly in turn influence usage. I'm not sure whether they give usage recommendations, such as the useful ones in the AHDEL ( eg at http://www.thefreedictionary.com/comprise ). And of course, I'm not advocating a grammar police. But a grammar / lexis referee now...

Comment: Dictionaries are naturally fans of the printed word. That doesn't make them arbiters of what "word" means. They define some words, but they define phrases and affixes too; and most of them don't say anything useful about grammar. Nah, quoting a dictionary definition of _word_ (especially one that gives a stupid pronunciation like _wûrd_) is essentially as effective as proving that God exists because it says so in the Bible.

Comment: Professor Lawler (I assume Emeritus, but I'm not going to check for the correct way to address you) - you are to grammar what Bill Shankly was to football (soccer). A famous quote: 'Some people say football is a matter of life and death - but it's more important than that.'

Comment: If you mean that I think grammar is an appropriate discussion topic in a grammar forum, yes. I've never heard of Shankly so I don't know whether to appear honored or insulted; but it's football, so it doesn't matter. This is English Grammar and Usage, not football. Or so I thought.

Comment: From the Home Page: Ask about...

Word choice and usage
Grammar
Etymology (history of words’ development)
Dialect differences
Pronunciation (phonetics and phonology, dialectology)
Spelling and punctuation. 

But a good soccer team needs defenders, midfielders, wingers, strikers, and a goalkeeper. And a manager who keeps everybody on their toes and has won every trophy available - and has never heard of cricket. (The sporting metaphor, British flavor)

Comment: The underlying problem here has cropped up again in more recent threads. The adoption of a definition of 'word' to include 'an open-space-bounded group of letters derived from an accepted word by extending the domain of derivational morphemes in a way seen before and governed by some restrictions' is being used to license 'new words' whose meaning is non-deducible and not given in dictionaries. I feel this is unhelpful and, when this definition is presented as unassailable, potentially dangerous. I feel that at least a 'moot' or 'contentious' (or similar) tag needs to be included.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the area of “Speech, utterance, verbal expression.”, the OED says that the ***word*** has this primary sense: “

> **1**. *collect. pl.* Things said, or something said; speech, talk, discourse, utterance; esp. with possessive, what the person mentioned says or said; (one’s) form of expression or language.
>
> Often in such phrases as ***in these, other, etc. words,*** in (such-and-such) language; ***many words, few words*** (see also (def#22), (def#26)); ***to give words to, to put into words,*** to express by means of language; ***beyond words,*** incapable of being expressed in language, unutterable, unspeakable.”

So ***words*** are anything that’s expressed using language.  As you might imagine, the full entry is longer than most religious tracts handed out by the most studious of proselytizers. Another interesting and applicable, and noteworthy, sense is sense *2*:

> **2a.** *sing.* Something said (= sense (def#1)); a speech or utterance; esp. defined by a possessive or demonstrative. arch.
>
> **2b.** with negative expressed or implied, or with *every*: Any or the least utterance, statement, or fragment of speech; anything at all (said or written).

Those are the first few parts of the first two senses. There are 29 distinct (or reasonably distinct) primary senses given for ***word*** in the OED, including almost uncountably many compounds.

Comment: This is disingenuous, a half-answer, not emphasising sufficiently the sense of intelligible communication. And if you say that you started with 'Regarding the area of “Speech, utterance, verbal expression.” ', it shouldn't be offered as an answer, as it obviously doesn't address the sense the OP is discussing. If words are totally utterance- and utterer- orientated, what is the point of dictionaries?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I actually have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: OP: 'My opinion is that a word is a word if it can be understood and defined by _everyone who hears it_ in conversation.' (not a workable definition, but it addresses the heart of the matter - _word_, in arguably its primary sense, and certainly not in a secondary sense, is a unit of _communication_, and thus is not applicable to (widely)  unintelligible strings - whether they are hoped to be decipherable or not. The AHDEL's first sense is: 1. A sound or a combination of sounds, or its representation in writing or printing, that symbolizes and **communicates a meaning** (bolding mine).

Comment: This seems germane: (Wikipedia, at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoword ): A **pseudoword** is a unit of speech or text that appears to be an actual word in a certain language (at least superficially), while in fact it has no meaning in the lexicon. It is a kind of non-lexical vocable. Another link (Nordquist) provides the delightful synonyms _jibberwacky_ and _wug word_.